# I need a function with the subsequent nature

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, logarithms, exponential-function

Suppose I have a quantity Q. I need a function, and if I multiply that function with Q, the product will become close to zero or Q reduces significantly. If it is exponential and logarithmic, then it will be better for me.

For example, Ae^(-KU)is a function where A is any constant value greater than zero, K is shape parameter which is also positive and can take any value then if we multiply this function to any large quantity like Q then a increasing value of U provides reduced value of product term.

Now I need another similar type of function which can reduce the value faster than this function.

Comment: What about $Ae^{-KU^2}$ or $Ae^{-Ke^U}$ ?

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Could you please give some more detail for your task? Thanks

Comment: Its working but I need more efficient function which can reduce faster than these two functions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: We can proceed with $Ae^\left({-Ke^{\left(e^U\right)}}\right)$

Comment: No no. single exponential function need because I have a condition where if I put the value of U to zero then total value of exponential term must be one.

Comment: Have you already tried with $Ae^{-KU^n}$ and $n$ large?

Comment: Yes, it provides almost same result